# Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the reliability of some items, using itemAnalysis().
My data sample consists of 24 items on a Likert scale, with 50 samples.

I keep getting the same Error, see picture:

[image: Error]

This is the simple code that is supposed to work:

```r
itemAnalysis(Mindset[,1:24])
```

What can I try to solve this problem?

Comment: (1) Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly. (2) Without seeing `Mindset`, it could be anything; without knowing non-base packages you're using (it is not the [`itemAnalysis`](https://github.com/cran/itemanalysis/blob/master/NAMESPACE#L19) package), we can't know what it is trying to do.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Iris Van Vliet! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Voting to close for lack of response to excellent new user assistance.